# Shopping cart calculating total

Tags: php, cart

Good day, below is a piece of code that increments the total cost for each product in the session array. My problem is displaying 0 at the end of the total when the last peny = 0.

Example 1, 2.20 + 2.20 = 4.40 but only 4.4 is shown

Example 2, 2.20 + 2.25 = 4.45 and 4.45 is shown

```
$total = 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['cartItems'])){
    foreach ($_SESSION['cartItems'] as $product){
        $total += $product['cost'];
    }
}
echo $total;
```

Any advice on how to show/include when a 0 is entered?

Comment: Try `echo number_format($total,2);` - more info on this here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php (the ,2 parameter dictates the amount of decimal places.) or if you want to get more technical - http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: That worked, thank you

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. A word of caution though... just use this for display purposes. If you apply this to a number and then use that number in a calculation later you will get in to all sorts of problems.... you have been warned :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was already answered in a comment by **WebCode.ie** but here is a detailed answer that may help those facing the same problem:

To customize a number format, you can use the PHP Function `string number_format()` , that accepts either **one**, **two**, or **four** ***parameters***, this way:

```
$my_number=25200;    
$number_decimals=2;
$dec_separator=".";
$thousands_separator=" ";

echo number_format($my_number , $number_decimals, $dec_separator, $thousands_separator);

// This will output 25 200.00
```

1. The number you want to format
2. The number of decimals
3. The decimal separator
4. The thousands separator

**Please also note that you can only use 1, 2 or 4 parameters.**